# How to reshape an array using np tile

Tags: python, numpy

I have a array X structured with shape 2, 5 as follows:

```
0, 6, 7, 9, 1
2, 4, 6, 2, 7
```

I'd like to reshape it to repeat each row n times as follows (example uses n = 3):

```
0, 6, 7, 9, 1
0, 6, 7, 9, 1
0, 6, 7, 9, 1
2, 4, 6, 2, 7
2, 4, 6, 2, 7
2, 4, 6, 2, 7
```

I have tried to use np.tile as follows, but it repeats as shown below:

```
np.tile(X, (3, 5))
0, 6, 7, 9, 1
2, 4, 6, 2, 7
0, 6, 7, 9, 1
2, 4, 6, 2, 7
0, 6, 7, 9, 1
2, 4, 6, 2, 7
```

How might i efficiently create the desired output?

Comment: Without proper display formatting you starting array looked like a flat 10 element!  Hence the answer has a `a.reshape(2, 5)` step.  Reviewing the question after posting is a good idea.

Comment: You did not get that result from a (3,5) tile.  From a (3,1) yes. `np.tile` use `np.repeat`, but the pattern is different.  It treats your array as a block, a tile, that is repeated in a pattern. Did you look at the `np.tile` docs after it failed on you (or better yet before using)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` be the main array:

```
a = np.array([0, 6, 7, 9, 1, 2, 4, 6, 2, 7])
```

we can do this by first reshaping to the desired array shape and then use `np.repeat` as:

```
b = a.reshape(2, 5)
final = np.repeat(b, 3, axis=0)
```

It can be done with `np.tile` too, but it needs unnecessary extra operations, something as below. So, `np.repeat` will be the better choice.

```
test = np.tile(b, (3, 1))
final = np.concatenate((test[::2], test[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

For complex repeats, I'd use `np.kron` instead:

```
np.kron(x, np.ones((2, 1), dtype=int))
```

For something relatively simple,

```
np.repeat(x, 2, axis=0)
```